# SpyOn SideNav does not find given method

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I have a side navigation menu in my test project and i want to write a simple test to check that the sidenav opens (**toggles**) when i click the button. The AppComponent itself references to sidebar via its dependency sidenavbar.

```js
it('when button is clicked, sidenav appears', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let sidenav_button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.sidenavbar.opened).toBeFalsy();
    spyOn(component.sidenavbar, 'toggle');
    sidenav_button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.sidenavbar.toggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

right now it says, the method toggle() does not exist to spy on it. I am pretty sure it actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `toggle` is private and you can't spy on it.

`sidenavbar` is an `object` within `AppComponent`, correct? It's not a child component?

If I were you, I would just see the `opened` property changed.

```
it('when button is clicked, sidenav appears', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let sidenav_button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.sidenavbar.opened).toBeFalsy();
    // spyOn(component.sidenavbar, 'toggle');
    sidenav_button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.sidenavbar.opened).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: i also tried to take a look at opened property, but it was somehow UNDEFINED through all the lifecycle. But now i tried it again and it worked. Some kind of black magic, i suppose...